# Sending variables with ajax in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.4

This is my first time I'm doing this type of sending so I hope you can help me, I have a web page in laravel 5.4 which on a page I have a label that shows me a number and I want that number to appear On another page using ajax but I do not know how to do it.

This is the code of my page that I have the label (which I want to send):

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 siga-cantidad">
    <label id="preciototalEmpresarialSiga">$25.000</label>
</div>
```

I want that value to appear in another label on my page / tests that I also have my controller and my route.

This is my route

```
Route::get('/prueba', 'PruebaController@index')->name('prueba');
```

This is my controller

```
class PruebaController extends Controller
{     
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pruebas');
    }

}
```

And I do not know how to do with ajax to send me that data of my label. I hope I could be clear and they can help me, in advance many thanks to all.

---

Yes, I think I was not very clear ... I have this web page in laravel 5.4, it is in the path and in the controller

```
Route::get('/portal-de-calidad', 'PortalController@index')->name('portal');
class PortalController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('portal');
    }
}
```

In this url(/portal-de-calidad) I have this code

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 siga-cantidad">
    <label id="preciototalEmpresarialSiga">$25.000</label>
</div>
```

What I want is that the "$ 25.00" that is inside the label is displayed in another web page .. I understand that with ajax can be done but I do not know how to start or where to put the code ...
Here I put the route and the driver of the page where I want the information appears obviously on another label ..

```
    Route::get('/prueba', 'PruebaController@index')->name('prueba');
<label>"Here I want you to show me the information on the portal page"</label>
    class PruebaController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('prueba');
        }

    }
```

I hope I have been clear and can understand and help me ... thanks ..!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here but for sending data using ajax to a specific route following should suffice :

AJAX Call

```
function postLabel()
        {
          var value = $('#preciototalEmpresarialSiga').text();
          $.ajax({
            url : "{{url('/prueba')}}",
            type : "GET",
            data : { 'price' : value },
            success:function(data){//200 response comes here
              //Do what you want to do with processed data
            }, 
            error:function(e){
            //Error handling
            }
          })
        }
```

And in your Controller

```
public function index()
{
    if( !Input::has('price') )//Check if input exist     
        return response('Bad request', 400);
    $price = Input::get('price');
    //Also you should validate your data here
    //Process data 
    return $price; 
}
```

Comment: Disculpa creo q no me supe explicar biien ... en mi etiqueta label tengo un numero .... ahora quiero que ese numero se muestre en otra pagina ... espero esta vez me entiendas y puedas ayudarme .... !! Gracias y disculpa por contestar recien ... la ruta del codigo que quiero enviar es esta Route::get('/portal', 'PortalController@index')->name('portal'); aqui esta el dato que quiero enviar a mi otra pagina q su ruta es Route::get('/prueba', 'PruebaController@index')->name('prueba');